# Python : error with importing md5

Tags: python, md5

I have problem with importing  md5 library
I just use the code below:

```
import md5
filemd5 = md5.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
```

I also have tried this code :

```
from hashlib import md5
filemd5 = md5.new(password.strip()).hexdigest()
```

also this code :

```
from md5 import md5
```

But none of them are working !
when I run the code,it gives me this error:

```
11.py", line 1, in <module>
import md5
ImportError: No module named 'md5'
```

What Should I Do ?
Am I Importing The Wrong Library ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: The `md5` _module_ has been deprecated since Python 2.5 and it does not exist in Python 3.  `from hashlib import md5` _should_ work. What error did it give you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`md5` is not a module, it is an object. But it has no `new` method. It just has to be built, like any object.

Use as follows:

```
import hashlib

m=hashlib.md5(b"text")
print(m.hexdigest())
```

The `b` prefix is required by Python 3, and is understood (and ignored by python 2.7). Older versions of python 2 don't accept it (just pass `"text"` as a string)

results in:

```
1cb251ec0d568de6a929b520c4aed8d1
```

You can also create the object empty and update it afterwards (more than once!)

```
m=hashlib.md5()
m.update(b"text")
m.update(b"other text")
s = "some more text"
m.update(s.encode())
```

note that Python 3 requires an encoded `bytes` object, not `string`, because Python 3 makes a difference between string and binary data. MD5 is useful on binary and strings.