# md5 not support in python 3.6 and django 1.10

Tags: python, django, ccavenue

I want to decrypt response received from CCavenue.In their refrence code they use md5 library but for django 1.10 with python 3.6 not supported.

```
import md5
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'md5'

Comment: `from hashlib import md5`?

Comment: As a side note: you can not *decrypt* MD5. It's a hash algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : error with importing md5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423542/python-error-with-importing-md5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python3.x,you should use this:

```
from hashlib import md5
```

> You can now feed this object with **bytes-like** objects (normally
>   bytes) using the update() method.

e.g.

```
from hashlib import md5

m = md5()
m.update(b"Nobody")
print(m.hexdigest())
```

> Module name:   md5 .
>   Rationale:     Replaced by the 'hashlib' module.
>   Date:          15-May-2007 .
>   Documentation: Documented as deprecated as of Python 2.5, but listing
>   in this PEP was neglected.DeprecationWarning raised as of Python 2.6.

See more details from [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply when i am using hashlib library thrn giving error as:-   'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'new'  at this line  encDigest = md5.new ()

Comment: @MEWEBTECHNOLOGIES Do you mean `hashlib.new` See [hashlib.new](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.new).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But when I am using hashlib and decrypt my response it return non readable string as :-    0d609f1857d838c7ae0bdcd8df1fe51db2dd1286d30aa0699190bb154fce5584da01ecfbba8596e0a409de2679fbbb51b55617e4639505d02bcb.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `McGrady`'s answer.

Here is my detailed explanation:

- [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html)

  - `md5` is single module

    - not merged into `hashlib`
  - `update()` support `str`

    - not `bytes`
  - Special: for `Python 2.7`, `md5` has merged to `hashlib` but `update()` still support `str`
  - code:

```
try:
    import md5
except ImportError:
    from hashlib import md5

def generateMd5(strToMd5) :
    encrptedMd5 = ""
    md5Instance = md5.new()
    #<md5 HASH object @ 0x1062af738>
    md5Instance.update(strToMd5)
    encrptedMd5 = md5Instance.hexdigest()
    #af0230c7fcc75b34cbb268b9bf64da79
    return encrptedMd5
```

---

- [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)

  - `md5` has merged into `hashlib`
  - `update()` only support `bytes`

    - not support `str`
  - code:

```
from hashlib import md5 # only for python 3.x

def generateMd5(strToMd5) :
    """
    generate md5 string from input string
    eg:
        xxxxxxxx -> af0230c7fcc75b34cbb268b9bf64da79
    :param strToMd5: input string
    :return: md5 string of 32 chars
    """
    encrptedMd5 = ""
    md5Instance = md5()
    # print("type(md5Instance)=%s" % type(md5Instance)) # <class '_hashlib.HASH'>
    # print("type(strToMd5)=%s" % type(strToMd5)) # <class 'str'>
    bytesToMd5 = bytes(strToMd5, "UTF-8")
    # print("type(bytesToMd5)=%s" % type(bytesToMd5)) # <class 'bytes'>
    md5Instance.update(bytesToMd5)
    encrptedMd5 = md5Instance.hexdigest()
    # print("type(encrptedMd5)=%s" % type(encrptedMd5)) # <class 'str'>
    # print("encrptedMd5=%s" % encrptedMd5) # 3a821616bec2e86e3e232d0c7f392cf5
    return encrptedMd5
```